# Set-SPUser - not valid user object - 19;#username - powershell

Tags: powershell, groups, spuser

I'm trying to add users to a custom "responsible" group that have the same permissions as owners group.

I'm getting member from a list in SP (people and group).

```
$Responsible = GetTeamSiteResponsible
$ResponsibleGroup = $web.SiteGroups["Responsible"]

if ($Responsible -ne $null) 
{
    foreach ($Member in $Responsible)
    {
        try 
        { 
            #$SPUser = $web.EnsureUser($Member.User) 
            if($Member -ne $null) 
            { 
                #$ResponsibleGroup.AddUser($SPUser) 
                Set-SPUser -Identity $Member -Web $web -Group $ResponsibleGroup
            } 
            else 
            { 
                LogError "Error adding user $member in $ResponsibleGroup" $false
            } 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
            LogError "Error adding $Member" $false
        } 
    }
}
```

I've tried to use EnsureUser but it also fails.

Problem is that $member is not a spuser, it's only a string like (19;#username).

What's the best way to solve this, how to convert 19:#username to spuser?

Comment: You should do `EnsureUser`passing in only the loginname part of your string

Comment: Ty @RobertLindgren, that worked. But what's the best way to trim the string?

Comment: If you know regex you could probably do some fancy, but since we are sure of the format of the string (it is a lookup) we can use Substring()

Comment: This will work: `$userName = $member.Substring($member.IndexOf("#") + 1)`.